# Как я могу очистить только одно поле select в форме при помощи JS?

Tags: javascript

Например в этом коде поле выбора нужно очистить значения только в select id="svet":

```html
<select id="pol">
  <option value="1">Дефолт</option>
  <option value="1.1">Что-то 1</option>
  <option value="1.2">Что-то 2</option>
  <option value="1.3">Что-то 3</option>
</select>
<select id="svet">
  <option value="1">Дефолт-1</option>
  <option value="1.1">Значение 1</option>
  <option value="1.2">Значение 2</option>
</select>
<button>Очистить</button>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('svet')` чем вас не устраивает?

Comment: не могу понять, я пробовал и не срабатывает, документы по этому не нашел (

Comment: https://codepen.io/_Poetiq_/pen/ZERdLXE

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант...

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', _ => {
  document.querySelector('#svet').value = ''
})
```

```html
    <select id="pol">
      <option value="1">Дефолт</option>
      <option value="1.1">Что-то 1</option>
      <option value="1.2">Что-то 2</option>
      <option value="1.3">Что-то 3</option>
    </select>
    <select id="svet">
      <option value="1">Дефолт-1</option>
      <option value="1.1">Значение 1</option>
      <option value="1.2">Значение 2</option>
    </select>
    <button>Очистить</button>
```

Comment: нужен дефолт доставленный ) но то же вариант спасибо

Comment: Какой "дефолт доставленный"?

Comment: @Poetiq, вместо строки `document.querySelector('#svet').value = ''` пишите `document.querySelector('#svet').selectedIndex = 0;` и будет вам дефолтный

Comment: @Deonis спасибо очень хороший вариант!